A question about tridiagonal complex symmetric matrix
I discovered a pattern when doing numerical experiments, a matrix with following form (tridiagonal, symmetric, real main diagonal,imaginary secondary diagonal):
$$
M=
\begin{bmatrix}
k_1 &ig_1 &&\\
ig_1 &k_2 &ig_2 &\\
 &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots\\
&&ig_{n-2}&k_{n-1}&ig_{n-1} \\
 & & &ig_{n-1} &k_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The unit eigenvector corresponding to its paired complex eigenvalues ​​has a square sum of the odd-numbered elements equal to 0.5 (the same is true for even-numbered elements).
or, if $\lambda$ is a complex eigenvalue, $u$ is the unit eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$, then:
$$
\sum_{i\text{ is odd}}|u_i|^2=\sum_{i\text{ is even}}|u_i|^2=0.5
$$
For example:
An example for 5-dimension matrix
From top to bottom they are：
The matrix; eigenvalues; unit eigenvectors; squared modulus; sum of odd elements, even elements (sum of 1,3,5 rows, sum of 2,4 rows of former matrix).
You can see that the sum in complex eigenvalues equal to 0.5, and the real eigenvalue don't have this property.
So how to interpret or prove this? thx
